# How to find this sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

One step away from finishing my proof but not sure how to do this sum:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix} i\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}$$

If it's not easy, if you could explain why, that would be great so I remember for next time

This is what I've done so far
$$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix} i+1\\ k\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} (\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ k\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}i\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}) = 2^{i} + \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix}i\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Reading my own answer is this correct?:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} (\begin{pmatrix} i\\ k\end{pmatrix} = 2^{i} $$

Comment: the sum starts at 1.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but any particular reason why you aren't writing it as $$\sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k}$$

Comment: @mookid yes presumably it should, but just out of curiosity, *if* you had to define $\binom{i}{-1}$ isn't $0$ the most sensible choice?

Comment: hint: this is just all the possible ways you could choose a subset from a set with i elements. you might be able come up with a different way to count this.

Comment: yes it would. you can also note $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} \binom ik$

Comment: Sort of confused by what your saying, we haven't be taught crap all

Comment: @Sabyasachi: no, in your sum it starts for $k=0$!

Comment: @mookid well presumably since $\binom{i}{-1}$ is $0$ anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is answer? DOn't see how you got there

Answer (score 4):

You can recognize this as Newtons binomium (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), which says that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^iy^{n-i} = (x+y)^n.
$$
You can prove this by induction. In your case the answer would be $2^i$.

An intuitive way to see the solution is to realize that this sum represents all possible ways to choose a subset from a set of $i$ elements. For each element in the whole set you can choose to include it or not, giving two different subsets. Thus the total sum must be $2^i$.

Comment: I am doing an, inductive proof, this is my inductive step

Comment: Something you will need to prove first is that $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k}$, which again should be done by induction. Note that the wikipedia link contains a proof;)

Comment: Edited my question, already prove that earlier in my answer, just not typing it out, just need to do this last summation

Comment: Note that the last sum is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{i}\binom{i}{k}$, which equals $2^i$. So you get $2^i + 2^i = 2*2^i = 2^{i+1}$.

Comment: Reading my own answer is this correct?: 

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} (\begin{pmatrix} i\\ k\end{pmatrix} = 2^{i} $$

Comment: Yes it is. (characters)